# Jenkins Deploy Plugin to Multiple Tomcat Servers

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, tomcat7, jenkins-plugins

I would like to use Jenkins Deploy Plugin to deploy my war file to multiple remote tomcat 7 servers.

Via the UI i can only do one server though.  Once I select 'Deploy war/ear to a container', I cannot select it again.  The option is greyed out.

Note the deployment to the one server works just fine, I just want to be able to deploy to multiple servers.  Can I do this with Jenkins Deploy Plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, I believe that is the limitation of this plugin in jenkin. Ideally it should allow us to deploy the same war on more than one servers.Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree.  Unfortunately I had to bypass this plugin and build my own steps that allowed me to deploy to multiple servers.